# Angular JS Touch and Swipe

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch

I am very new to angular JS and working on a mobile application. As a part of it, I need to write a service that handles touch events like swipe-left, swipe-right, swipe-up and swipe down and I need to call back depending on which action is made. Please let me know if there any useful tutorials.

Comment: What you are looking for is already available in angular-touch. Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments ngTouch is a good place to start, however it only has swipe left and swipe right. I recommend using [Angular Gestures](https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures); it's an angular implementation of hammer.js, and has pretty much everything you'd ever need:

- doubletap
- dragstart
- drag
- dragup
- dragdown
- dragleft
- dragright
- dragend
- hold
- pinch
- pinchin
- pinchout
- release
- rotate
- swipe
- swipeup
- swipedown
- swipeleft
- swiperight
- tap
- touch
- transformstart
- transform
- transformend

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the [angular-swipe](https://github.com/marmorkuchen-net/angular-swipe) module. It replaces `ng-swipe` and uses the same directives, adding up and down:

```
ng-swipe-up
ng-swipe-down
ng-swipe-left
ng-swipe-right
```

Answer (score 1):

In html i used 5 tabs and i am able to swipe left or right smoothly. 
my code given below.

**RECEIVED**  |  **SENT**  |  **DELETED**  |  **ARCHIVED**   **Reports**

In html

ng-swipe-left="leftTab()" ng-swipe-right="rightTab()"

and In controller.

```
$scope.leftTab = function(){
     if($scope.tab != 4 ){
        $scope.getAlertsSummary($scope.tab + 1);
    }
};

$scope.rightTab = function(){
    if($scope.tab != 0 ){
        $scope.getAlertsSummary($scope.tab - 1);
    }
};
```

Here getAlertsSummary used for get tab data.